# Mutual C++ classes declared inside of a function

Tags: c++, class, inner-classes, local-class

How do I define classes inside of a function so that they "know" about each other?  Here is a greatly dumbed down version of what I'm trying to understand.  I'd like to do something like:

```
void foo () {

    struct A {
        static void bar () {
            B::hmm();
        }
    };

    struct B {
        static void hmm () {
            A::bar();
        }
    }
}
```

That doesn't work because A::bar() doesn't know anything about B yet.  Outside of a function, I could defer the definition of A::bar() until after B is declared.  Something like:

```
void foo () {

    struct A {
        static void bar ();
    };

    struct B {
        static void hmm () {
            A::bar();
        }
    }

    void A::bar () {
        B::hmm();
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work inside of a function.

In lieu of some clever scoping declaration that makes this all work, I'd also welcome a definitive answer saying this is just not possible in C++ (reference please).

I know there are other ways to work around this (declaring the classes outside of foo, for instance), so I'm not looking for answers on how to do something similar...

Comment: Why can't you just use a namespace?

Comment: @GWW, I take it you didn't read my last sentence.

Comment: I did read it, but I'm curious why you can't use a namespace and need to use a function.

Comment: @GWW, there's no reason I can't do any of a dozen roughly equivalent things.  I was just hoping to learn another detail about the language.  The reason I find this interesting is because it limits the scope of those classes to the only place they should be seen or used.

Comment: Ah okay I was just curious, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

Member functions of local classes must be defined inside of the class definition.

Because the definitions of `A::bar()` and `B::hmm()` are mutually dependent and because member functions cannot be forward declared outside of a class definition, there is no way to order the definitions such that this can work.

(You said you aren't looking for workarounds, but I'll say anyway that, in my opinion, defining any remotely complex class, more or less multiple classes, inside a function definition, hinders code readability and is a bad idea.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I found some documentation on an IBM site that says basically the same thing.  The phrase "local class" is what I was missing in my Google search.  However, it wasn't a question about style or readability, so if you delete that last bit, I'll give you credit for the answer.

Comment: @xscott:  I think the comment about readability is important.  You are, of course, free not to accept this answer if you don't want to.